# Having a base Url set in web.config and red from angularjs resource function, possible?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, web-config

I was wondering if it is possible to set a base url in the web.config for my resource functions and then read the url from the Web.Config file in angular.

I have not just set up a js file as my configuration file were all my urls are read from but i would like to have them in the app settings as keys. some of them at least.

Is this good practice or even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a separate file(file_name.constant.js), containing the keys and their value's as the url path.

The constant file will look as(file name for eg: app.constant.js):

```
angular.module('ModuleName').constant('AppConstant', {
    APP_URL: "url_path"
});
```

In order to use the above url, you just have to include the constant module(**AppConstant**) as the dependency, into the respective file (service/controller).

For eg, if you are using ui-router, then you can use it as:

```
angular.module('ModuleName').factory('AppService',['AppConstant','$http',function(AppConstant, $http){
    function getData(){
         var request = $http({
              method: 'GET',
              url: AppConstant.APP_URL // access the constant url
         })
         return request.then(function(response){
             return response;
         })
    }
}]);
```